# CakePHP 2.0 give empty response using _serialize

Tags: api, cakephp-2.0

I'm using the serialize key to output data in json format. Is there a way to output nothing, just an empty response with application/json as content-type? I've tried null, an empty string and an empty array as a serialize value but nothing seems to do the trick.

Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to not use the _serialize method and instead use a custom view. See: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files

You can make all your actions use the same view file via `$this->render('my_custom_view');` instead of creating a new view file for each.